# Error deploying spring project

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat

I am getting the following upon deployment:

```
7/Dez/2013 19:38:03 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/meuProjeto]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:142)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  ... 11 more
7/Dez/2013 19:38:03 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\meuProjeto.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/meuProjeto]]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Any further caused by?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: show your web.xml and applictionContext.xml

Comment: @DavidLevesque - I'm using the version 3.1.0

Comment: @MinGyooJung - I could not format properly my xml here, so I put him in pastebin.com. web.xml - http://pastebin.com/8vhfSQgd, context.xml http://pastebin.com/iGqT2Ekm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems related to this bug reported in [SPR-8496](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8496). Try to upgrade the spring version to get the bug fixed.

Comment: I upgraded the spring to 3.2.5 and worked! Thank you!

Comment: After upgrade the css don't load anymore. If I back to 3.1.0.M2 the CSS load with no problems. Anybody knows the reason?